# Get right size in SpriteSkit with Swift?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

how can I get the current size of the screen which is rendered in my scene in Swift?

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        // how to get the size of the current screen that is rendered?        
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really get your question .. but:

to get the view rect, get its frame property

```
print(view.frame)
```

you can also get the screen scale if you want

```
print(UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
```

Comment: If they're looking for specificity, `view.frame.size.height` and `view.frame.size.width`. Or even more specifically, for the rendered scene (which may have constraints that differ from scene to scene) `self.frame.size.height` and `self.frame.size.width` .

Answer (score 0):

You can also use UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeBounds.width/height to get the screen size directly.